# How to pass method return value into another method as a string parameter?

Tags: c#

I've been learning C# for the past few weeks now and I need to pass the return values from `Method1` and `Method2` into `Method3` but as string parameters so that I may interpolate the values into the body of `Method3`. Any advice on how to do such a thing?

```
string Method1()
{
        //Do Stuff Here
        return result
}
string Method2()
{
        //Do Stuff Here
        return result
}
void Method3()
{
        //String Interpolation Here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understood what you're looking for Correctly. In that case this example should give you the answer you're looking for.

You can use `$` infront of a string and then call method inside `{}`

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        Method3($"{Method1()} {Method2()}");
        Method4();
    }

    public static string Method1()
    {
        //Do Stuff Here
        return "Hello";
    }

    public static string Method2()
    {
        //Do Stuff Here
        return "World";
    }

    public static void Method3(string input)
    {
        // If String interpolation is done within the Method Call
        Console.WriteLine(input);
    }


    public static void Method4()
    {
        // String Interpolation, calling initial two methods from within the third method.
        Console.WriteLine($"{Method2()} {Method1()}");
    }
```

Comment: Think of `$` as `String.Format`, if you ever need to concatenate more than two or three strings then use a `StringBuilder` which won't allocate new string everytime you append/concatenate.

Comment: @JeremyThompson Thanks for the additional details, should've mentioned them for clarity! The edit seems to be not what the comments show in the OPs post. I'd add it as a secondary example, not overwrite the original code.

Comment: I just added method4 which should cover both cases.